# Problem Configuring "Location" Path Security on Machine.config

Tags: asp.net, configuration, path, web-config, machine.config

I'm trying to add something like this in Machine.config:

```
<location path="elmah.axd">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="domain\johnny" />
            <deny users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This works great in the application-level web.config, but I can't get it to take any effect in machine.config.  Basically, I'm trying to set security for the "elmah.axd" path in all applications.  The security is not being applied when this code is placed in the machine.config or root/server-level web.config.  It lets all users access "elmah.axd" no matter what I do.

Comment: Hi Scott. Did you ever find the solution for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your not overriding it in the web.config